# How do I rebind my Telerik MVC grid after an item has been inserted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid

My Telerik MVC 3 grid is filled via Ajax.  After inserting a row I need to rebind my grid. When I'm doing a rebind on the OnSave() event the data rebind is still sending on the Controller Action. I need something like an OnInserted event.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the following criteria,**

```
 @(Html.Telerik().Grid<PackageDetails>()
     .Name("gvPackage")
     .DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(k => k.PKG_CODE))
     .Columns(column =>
     {
        column.Bound(c => c.PKG_NAME).Title("Description").Width(200);
        column.Bound(c => c.MESG_UNIT).Title("Measuring Unit").Width(100);
        column.Bound(c => c.STD_QNT).Title("Quantity").Width(100);
        column.Bound(c => c.MODEL).Title("Model").Width(100);

        column.Bound(c => c.COMP_CODE).ClientTemplate("<input type='text' id='txtSerial<#=COMP_CODE#>' value='<#=PKG_NAME#>' />").Title("Serial Number");

        column.Bound(c => c.COMP_DESC).Title("Model").Width(100);
                                  })
        .DataBinding(dbBindings => dbBindings.Ajax().Select("_PackageDetailsLoad", "SalesDept"))
```

)

**Controller Code**

```
[GridAction]
        public ActionResult _PackageDetailsLoad(string programID, string projectID, string packageID)
        {
            objLoginHelper = (LoginHelper)Session["LogInInformation"];

            return View(new GridModel<PackageDetails>
            {
                Data = salesDal.ReadPackageDetails(programID, projectID, packageID)
            });
        }
```

**In JavaScript use the following Code**

```
$('#ddlProgram').change(function () {          
     LoadPackageAndBindGrid();
 });

function LoadPackageAndBindGrid() {

            var params = {
                programID: $('#ddlProgram').val(),
                projectID: $('#ddlProject').val(),
                packageID: $('#ddlPackage').val()
            };

            var grid = $('#gvPackage').data('tGrid');
            grid.dataSource._data = [];               

            // Reload The Package Details
            grid.ajaxRequest(params);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind your grid by returning a **GridModel** from your controller after performing your insert code:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
[GridAction]
public ActionResult _ItemInsert(int id, MyObject obj)
{
    //Rebind the grid by sending the GridModel back
    return View(new GridModel(myData)); // where myData is your grid data
}
```

Don't forget to decorate your controller with `[GridAction]`.

This assumes your grid has an ajax DataBinding declaration as follows:

```
dataBinding.Ajax()
.Insert("_ItemInsert", "Item" })
```

Comment: My model is bind to dropdown (

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're adding the row.  The grid should update automatically if you're doing in-grid editing.  If you're adding a record from a form, you can use the client-side rebind() method to refresh the grid data.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-client-api-and-events.html#rebind

Answer (score 0):

On Complete Of Your Action you can call:
jQuery("#gvPackage").data("t-grid").ajaxRequest()